# Django combobox dinamicos

Tags: django, django-forms

La consulta que tengo es la siguiente:

Ejemplo del modelo

```
class Marca(models.Model):

    marca = models.CharField(max_length=30)    

class Modelo(models.Model):

    modelo = models.CharField(max_length=30)    
    marca = models.models.ForeignKey()
```

Ejemplo del form

```
class miForm(forms.Form):

    marca = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Marca.objects.all())
    modelo = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Modelo.objects.all())
```

Al mostrarlos en mi template ambos están cargados con todos los registros, pero necesito que al seleccionar una marca del combobox me muestre los modelos asociados a esa marca.

Imagino que se podría filtrar ya desde el form por la marca seleccionada, pero eso es lo que no se como hacer, es posible pasarle el valor que selecciono el usuario al form para que haga la query con ese filtro?.

Lo otro que se me ocurre es inicializarlo vació y en base a la selección de marca en el view cargar los modelos de esa marca y pasarlo al template y ahí recién cargar.

Desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo y ayuda.

Comment: La única forma conocida es con AJAX. Cuando cambie el primer control, con AJAX haces una consulta a Django y con el resultado llenas el segundo control. Hay algunos paquetes que podrían ayudarte: https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/auto-complete/

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, alguna idea sin los paquetes de cómo hacerlo con ajax? No es posible hacerlo sin ajax con un submit y en el view cargar la información filtrada?

Comment: Puedes dividir tu formulario en dos pasos: en el primer paso solo seleccionas el primer control, en el segundo ya con los resultado filtrados presentas el resto del formulario.

Comment: Hay otra opción, que seria solo poner los Modelos (que de facto tienen associada una marca) y en el dropdown incluir Modelo y marca como texto. Con un Select2 te permitiría filtrar por modelo y marca.

Comment: [Este ejemplo resuelve la pregunta](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html) (en inglés)